# In neo4j, query to retrieve sub-chains shorter than a certain length

Tags: neo4j

In neo4j, I have nodes forming chains like this:

```
(b)-->(a)-->(b)-->(a)-->(b)-->(b)-->(b)-->(b)-->(a)-->(a)-->(b)-->(b)
```

I'm interested in short sub-chains consisting solely of (b)s. More specifically, I want to retrieve all (b)s that are part of sub-chains, where the length of the sub-chain is less than 4 (or some other integer). (b)s that are part of longer sub-chains should not be returned. The length could be 1. Thus in this case, the query should return all (b)s except for the 4 consecutive in the middle. How can I formulate a query for that?

Comment: How do you differentiate between `a` and `b` nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED]

Assuming all "b" nodes have the `B` label, this should work:

```
MATCH p=(x:B)-[*0..2]->(y:B)
WHERE ALL(n IN NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE n:B) AND NOT (:B)-->(x) AND NOT (y)-->(:B)
RETURN p
```

Chains of 1 through 3 `B` nodes will be joined by 0 through 2 relationships, hence the `[*0..2]` pattern is used.

Comment: There's the possibility of some non :B node being at the middle of that chain. Might need to add an `all(node in nodes(p) WHERE node:B)` to the WHERE clause to ensure it's an all :B chain.

Comment: @cybersam, do you agree with InverseFalcon? If so, could you update your answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks, @InverseFalcon. I forgot to add that, but now it has been fixed. There is no need to check the first and last node (again), hence the [1..-1].